# Error acceso con Microsoft.Office.Interop

Tags: vb.net, .net, excel, interop

Buenos días,
Tengo una aplicación en la que genero un Excel a partir de unos archivos html, todo funciona correctamente en local pero cuando lo publico en el servidor me funciona unas veces si y otras no.

No soy capaz de dar con la solucion, he configurado el servidor con los permisos correspondientes como he visto en algunos tutoriales dando acceso al usuario Servicio de Red.

Os pongo el código por si hago algo mal y el mensaje de error.

> No se pudo recuperar el generador de clases COM para el componente con CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} debido al siguiente error: 8000401a El proceso del servidor no se pudo iniciar debido a que la identidad configurada no es correcta. Compruebe el nombre del usuario y la contraseña. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x8000401A)

```vb
Dim xls As Excel.Application
Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim workbook2 As Excel.Workbook 

xls = New Excel.Application
workbook = xls.Workbooks.Open(miruta & "\mifichero.html")
workbook2 = xls.Workbooks.Open(miruta& "\fichero2.html")

workbook.Sheets(1).Columns("B:Z").ColumnWidth = 15
workbook.Sheets(1).Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 30

Dim HOJA_1 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets = workbook2.Sheets 

HOJA_1.Copy(Type.Missing, workbook.Sheets(workbook.Sheets.Count))
workbook.Sheets(workbook.Sheets.Count).Name = "RANKING"

workbook.Sheets(workbook.Sheets.Count).Columns("A:C").ColumnWidth = 50

Dim nombre = "Minombre"
workbook.SaveAs(miruta & "\" & miUsuario.Id_Usuario & "_" & nombre, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook,)

excelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close(0)
excelApp.Quit()

Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp)
excelApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] para ganar tu primera medalla y aprender como funciona el sitio. En cuanto a tu pregunta, echa un vistazo [aqui](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/305761/com-server-application-that-uses-interactive-user-identity-fails-to-lo). De todas maneras, Microsoft desaconseja totalmente usar Interop para aplicaciones web.

Comment: tienes  MS project instaldo en el servidor?